# How to change from binding ObervableCollection to a TabControl to a ContentControl

Tags: wpf

I'm very new to WPF and am writing an application using this example as a starting point
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090025

I will only have one workspace visible at any one time, so I want to get rid of the TabControl and use something simple instead - probably a ContentControl, I'm really not sure but all it needs to do is have content in and be closable. So I am trying to replace this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspacesTemplate"><TabControl 
  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemTemplate}"
  Margin="4"
  />
```

with:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspacesTemplate">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding ??}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemTemplate}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

but I don't know what to bind to. The code in the example seems to use CollectionViewSource to set the active workspace - it's the active workspace that I am interested in but I don't understand what TabControl is doing except that it's something to do with  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"

The template is invoked from here (Workspaces is the ObservableCollection of ViewModels):

```
<HeaderedContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Workspaces}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource   WorkspacesTemplate}" Header="Workspaces" Style="{StaticResource MainHCCStyle}"/>
```

and here is the ClosableItem template:

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="ClosableTabItemTemplate">
    <DockPanel Width="120">
        <Button 
    Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}"
    Content="X"
    Cursor="Hand"
    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
    Focusable="False"
    FontFamily="Courier" 
    FontSize="9"
    FontWeight="Bold"  
    Margin="0,1,0,0"
    Padding="0"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
    Width="16" Height="16" 
    />
        <ContentPresenter 
    Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    />
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Please can someone explain what I need to do? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WorkspacesTemplate` is telling WPF how to display the `Workspaces` property, which, as you say is an `ObservableCollection` of ViewModels.

So, the `WorkspacesTemplate` says, display all these ViewModels in a tab control, and for each ViewModel, use the `ClosableTabItemTemplate` to display the ViewModel in a tab.

Since you only want one workspace visible at a time, you don't need to expose a collection of workspaces from your ViewModel, and you don't need a tab control to display them. You simply expose the one current workspace from your ViewModel and provide some XAML to display it.

If you still want to use a template to wrap the ViewModel, then yes, you can just use a `ContentControl` to invoke the template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MySingleWorkspaceTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text={Binding Blah} />
    <!-- etc -->
</DataTemplate>
```

and to invoke the template

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentWorkspace}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MySingleWorkspaceTemplate}"/>
```

However, if this is the only place that the XAML is going to be used, you might as well forget the template and just declare the XAML directly. Eg, (instead of ContentControl)

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding CurrentWorkspace.Blah} />
<!-- etc -->
```

**EDITED TO ADD:**

I think you might be getting confused because currently the ViewModel has no concept of the "Selected Workspace", it just exposes a collection. For completeness (but don't worry about all this), the selection is introduced by the `TabControl` which indirectly uses the default `CollectionView` for the `Workspaces` collection, and `CollectionView` has the concept of a selected item. This is all in the view.

I wouldn't worry about any of this now, just expose the one workspace yourself from your ViewModel.

**EDIT2:**

Your close button is appearing because you are explicitly setting a `ContentTemplate` on your `HeaderedContentControl`. This template will appear regardless of `Content`.

To make a template only appear when there is data in `Content`, make the template implicit instead. If you add a `DataType` to your template definition (and remove the key), you tell WPF to always use this template to display an object of that data type.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:WorkspaceViewModel}">
    <!-- Blah -->
</DataTemplate>
```

Then you can remove the explicit template from your `HeaderedContentControl`. Simply setting the `Content` will be enough to invoke the template, and if there is no Content, there is no template.

```
<HeaderedContentControl Content="{Binding Path=CurrentWorkspace}" />
```

(ps. If you're not using the header of `HeaderedContentControl`, you might as well just use a bog standard `ContentControl`)

Comment: Yes, the bit I mainly didn't understand was how TabControl was interacting with the CollectionViewSource. Anyway, I'm struggling still. I have exposed CurrentWorkspace and am doing    <HeaderedContentControl Content="{Binding Path=CurrentWorkspace}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemTemplate}" (sorry I cannot format this as code in a reply, I dunno why) but nothing doing. I put INotifyPropertyChanged on CurrentWorkspace property in case it was that. I'll try and post my code in a minute.

Comment: Part of the problem is I don't even know what control to use. The ViewModels that I am loading are composites with lots of usercontrols in so I just want some closeable panel but I don't know if there is a panel type or what. I don't want Window, so that's why I was trying to keep the ClosableItem template.

Comment: The problem is that when I set CurrentWorkspace to the ViewModel the corresponding View isn't displayed.

Comment: A bog standard ContentControl is fine for displaying the template. If you want a close button, then use a Border control with a Button and ContentControl inside. Remember WPF is really flexible. You just build the layout you need rather than relying on loads of different controls.

Comment: Ok I've nearly got it. I needed to change the CloseableItem template's ContentPresenter's Content to just be Binding and not the DisplayName property. But is there a way to not do the CurrentWorkspace binding if CurrentWorkspace is null? Do I need a trigger?

Comment: If CurrentWorkspace is null, then the ContentPresenter will display nothing. If you want to display something else, then yes, you'll have to use a trigger.

Comment: In the CloseableItem template there is a close button  as well as the content presenter, that close button is getting displayed when CurrentWorkspace is null. How can I stop that?